# GLUT Warning: glutInit being called a second time

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

I am creating a program using a combination of QT and OpenGL. I get a warning when I try to initialize the OpenGL portion: GLUT Warning: glutInit being called a second time. I am only calling it once in my program. The program works on Linux based machines, but not on Macs.

Where the OpenGL is initially called from in the drawOpTableFunction:

```
n = ui->opTableSize->currentText().toInt();
basePatternCode = ui->basePatternChoose->currentText().toStdString().c_str()[0];

ui->modAddWidget->close();

ModNAdd modA(n);
modA.fillTable();
tiles = new Tile*[n];
for(int i = 0; i < n; i ++)
    tiles[i] = new Tile(m_color, basePatternCode);
drawOpTableFunction(modA.getTable(), tiles, n);
```

Where the drawOpTableFunction leads you:

```
void drawOpTableFunction(int **ta, Tile **ti, int en)
{
    table1 = ta;
    tiles1 = ti;
    n1 = en;
    HEIGHT = ((n1*50));
    WIDTH = ((n1*50));

    init_gl_window();
}
```

init_gl_window():

```
void init_gl_window()
{
    char *argv[] = {programName};
    int argc = sizeof(argv) / sizeof(argv[0]);
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode( GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DOUBLE );
    glutInitWindowSize(WIDTH,HEIGHT);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100,100);
    glutCreateWindow(programName);
    init();

    glutDisplayFunc(drawWindow);
    glutReshapeFunc(reshape);
    glutMainLoop();
}
```

As you can see, glutInit() is only called once.

Comment: Are you calling `init_gl_window` more than once? Put a print statement or breakpoint on it.

Comment: It's probalby because Qt calls the function somewhere internally - just leave it out and it should work

Answer (score 0):

Why are you pulling in GLUT if you're using Qt? GLUT is just some 3rd party framework. GLUT and Qt are filling the same spot. If you're using Qt, don't use GLUT. That simple.